# Save dataframe to file so that it can be reimported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm quite new to Python and I'm wondering what would be the best way to save a dataframe in a way so that it can be easily reimported. I'm running a code that checks for newly added files and imports them. In case it is stopped for any reason, I would like to reimport the last data that was saved before it stopped.

So, the data I'm interested in is in avg_data. To save it to txt, I use:

```
df_file_name = folder_path + '/' + file_name + '_lastData.txt'
        
        with open(df_file_name, "w") as new_file:
             avg_data.to_string(new_file, index=False)
```

But with this I struggle to properly reimport.. I use:

```
previous_data_str = folder_path + '/' + file_name + '_lastData.txt'
if os.path.isfile(previous_data_str) :
    old_data = pd.read_csv(previous_data_str)
```

to reimport, but this doesn't work... I don't get an error message but the data is now all in one column... using `sep="\t"` leads to the same, using `sep=" "` leads to too many empty columns... I uploaded a sample .txt file [here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/J5SHDJIEZp04U9P)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... and if it is even the best to save it in this way. I would greatly appreciate some tips on how to handle this best, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save it to csv with [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and then you can easily import it with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work nicely :)

Since I don't have continuous indices, I went with `avg_data.to_csv(df_file_name, index=True, index_label='index)` and `old_data = pd.read_csv(previous_data_str, index_col='index)` which seems to do the trick.